# Maven version auto-pom.xml

Tags: maven-2

Can anyone explain me if the version is specified as auto as mentioned below for the dependencies

```
<version>auto</version>
```

how does it get resolved to the latest from the maven repository?

I see that some file when mvn exectutes an temporary file called auto-pom.xml is generated where all the auto is replaced with proper latest revisions from my repository like

```
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: What version specified as 'auto'? Perhaps you could post some actual POM contents?

Comment: I wasn't even aware of this `<version>auto</version>`. Actually, I don't use any kind of automatic mechanism such as version ranges, LATEST, etc. I consider them as harmful for build reproducibility and thus a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is exactly but Maven implements a version comparison algorithm that you can check in the sources of [`org.a.m.a.v.DefaultArtifactVersion.java`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-artifact/xref/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/DefaultArtifactVersion.html). Also see the [Versioning](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Versioning) wiki page for an illustration and discussion of this algorithm.

Using this algorithm, I can imagine that Maven is able to check a repository for available versions and to determine the "latest" one.